# random numbers distributed across cells in Google Sheets

Tags: random, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

let's say I have 100 cells and I want to distribute numbers 1-100 across those 100 cells with no two cells having the same number.

is there a command in Google Sheets that would do this.

Please note the important things all 100 numbers in the range should be distributed across the 100 cells.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(VLOOKUP(QUERY({ROW(A1:A100), 
 RANDBETWEEN(ROW(A1:A100)^0, 9^9)}, "select Col1 order by Col2 asc"), 
 {ROW(A1:A100), ROW(A1:A100)}, 2, 0), 100, 1))
```

---

## UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(VLOOKUP(QUERY({ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&A1)), 
 RANDBETWEEN(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&A1))^0, 9^9)}, "select Col1 order by Col2 asc"), 
 {ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&A1)), ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&A1))}, 2, 0), A1, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I want to be able to select the range - looks like here it is hard-coded to be A1:A100

Comment: also 1-100 was just an example..I want to be able to use custom range as well 1-50, 1-150 etc. so some explanation of this would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: i just explanation of the above fomulae, if you can so that I can understand and apply as the formulae works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=arrayformula(row(A1:offset(A1,100-1,0)))
```

This will give you 1 to 100 in your cells (1 column, 100 row), you can change 100 with other number

If you would like between number you must change 1 to you begin value, for example 50 to 100:

```
=arrayformula(row(A50:offset(A50,100-50,0)))
```

Sorry, this not random number, but sequence number

For random number, you can just change A50:A100 (Mean random from 50 to 100) to your range for example A1:A30 (mean random from 1 to 30):

```
=query(arrayformula({(randbetween( 1,row(A50:A100))),row(A50:A100)}),"Select Col2 order by Col1")
```

Comment: Thanks all for your time and answers